# Нагрузочное тестирование для Delphi приложения

Tags: test-automation, нагрузочное-тестирование

Нужно провести нагрузочное тестирование с нагрузкой в 6000++ пользователей для серверно-ориентированного приложения WinApi. Написано на Delphi, имеет соединение с Oracle DB.

Пробывал всё сделать через Load Runner, но, как понимаю, в Vugen скрипт не запишешь, т.к нету протокола по которому можно записать WinApi. После этого, для написания скрипта, я воспользовался UFT Function Testing.

Хотелось бы узнать, как лучше всего сделать такую нагрузку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы скрипт записать, HP LoadRunner VuGen пригодится. А вот чтобы подать нагрузку в 6000+ пользователей, возможно, придётся использовать что-то другое. Зависит от того, что Вы подразумеваете под 6000+.

1. Если подразумевается, что должна создаться такая же нагрузка, какую бы создали бы 6000+ типичных пользователей системы. То тогда, возможно, HP LoadRunner сгодится. Перефразирую так - целевая интенсивность = 6000+ сценариев в час. Тогда надо записать скрипт, выполнить прогон скрипта без пауз и посмотреть, как долго выполняется, оценить шаг нагрузки - pacing. Пусть прогон скрипта одним пользователем занял 10 секунд. Тогда предполагаем, что под нагрузкой этот же сценарий уложится в 30 секунд и берём в качестве шага - 30 секунд. Тогда один виртуальный пользователь за час тестирования сможет выполнить 3600/30 = 120 сценариев, если каждый прогон уложится в 30 секунд. А чтобы выполнить 6000+ сценариев в час понадобится 6000/120 = 50 виртуальных пользователей HP LoadRunner.

Если же шаг нагрузки больше 30 секунд, тогда понадобится больше 50-ти пользователей. А в HP LoadRunner пользователей свыше 50-ти надо покупать, если не куплены. И тогда надо будет суметь обосновать бюджет или, возможно, переписать тест с использованием другого инструмента.

2. Если по требованиям нужно, чтобы было 6000+ соединений с сервером во время нагрузочного тестирования. То тогда точно нужно 6000+ виртуальных пользователей. Тут точно надо покупать, и купить 6000+ это неплохие деньги. Я бы тут использовал для запуска тестов Apache.JMeter. Да, скрипт записывал бы в LoadRunner, используя его возможности по перехвату вызовов и генерации кода, а запускал бы из JMeter. Вот пример, такого перехода на JMeter: https://github.com/pflb/wcfLoadTest. Пример для протокола WCF, пример учебный, пока не доделан. Суть та же, сначала надо реализовать работу с нужным протоколом (DCOM/COM+/WCF/WinAPI) из C# .NET, а потом .NET-клиента вызывать из JMeter с помощью jni4net.
3. Если нужно чтобы было 6000+ соединений на сервер, и тестируется двухзвенная система - нагрузка только на Oracle. То тогда тоже можно использовать JMeter со способом взаимодействия JDBC - базовая возможность.

Резюмирую, необходимое количество виртуальных пользователей также влияет на выбор инструмента для нагрузки. Так как HP LoadRunner в demo-режиме предоставляет 50 пользователей, а не 6000+. И если 6000+ это пользователи, а не интенсивность, то столько надо будет купить и быть к этому готовым. Или использовать бесплатные инструменты для подачи нагрузки.

Comment: Спасибо, возможно ли с вами связаться как нибудь по skype или другим средствам коммуникации ?

Comment: Почта есть - owasp на яндексе. Ещё школу тестирования провожу иногда по выходным, в Москве в офисе Перфоманс Лаб, на ул. Барклая. Там несколько преподавателей, каждый поможет. По будням занят, на письма отвечаю.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Могу ли я кам иногда обращаться по вопросам данного характера ?

Comment: Да, конечно, обращайтесь.

Comment: Спасибо, с удовольствием бы посетил ваши уроки, но жаль, что я из Минска, республика Беларусь

Answer (score 1):

Если серверная часть приложения, это DCOM-сервис на Delphi, то можно воспользоваться HP LoadRunner, выбирая при записи скрипта протокол COM/DCOM.

Если же речь идёт о тестировании двухзвенного приложения, которое представляет из себя толстый клиент на Delphi и базу данных Oracle, то нагрузочное тестирование является нагрузочным тестированием сервера базы данных. В таком случае протокол тот, который используется для соединения с сервером Oracle. Возможно используется ODBC, Oracle ThinClient, какие-то другие способы. В любом случае, эти протоколы также поддерживаются в LoadRunner для записи трафика и генерации кода нагрузочного скрипта.

Если приложение трёхзвенное, всё-таки, сервер написан на Delphi, а для связи клиент-сервер используется некий неизвестный протокол, то разбор трафика надо начинать с WireShark. Подключать декомпилятор Delphi (DeDe, для ранних версий Delphi работал неплохо). А потом писать своего нагрузочного клиента, повторно используя библиотечный код, используемый клиентским приложением.

Резюмирую, думаю что LoadRunner ещё рано списывать.

Comment: Спасибо за полный ответ, будем пробывать .